# Does the wired XBox 360 controller work with Surface 2

Tags: controllers, windows-rt

I'm looking at getting a gamepad for my Surface 2 running Windows RT. I would like to know if the wired XBox 360 controller works. All the stuff I've seen online shows the wireless one being used with the dongle. The controller I'm talking about specifically is [this one](http://www.bestbuy.ca/en-CA/product/microsoft-xbox-360-wired-controller-s9f-00001-black-s9f-00001/10157564.aspx?path=9d35a57082932e52b87fb16cdbe67d34en02)

Comment: I don't have a Surface, so I can't test it.  However, if the wireless+dongle one works, the wired one is actually *simpler* to work with.  I would think it would work fine.  You might be able to take your tablet to a local game shop and ask to borrow a used 360 controller for a quick test before you buy.  Usually they're pretty cool about that sort of thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Microsoft Compatibility Center](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/compatibility/CompatCenter/Home),  The [XBox 360 wired controller](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/compatibility/CompatCenter/ProductDetailsViewer?Name=Microsoft%20Xbox%20360%20Wired%20Game%20Controller&vendor=Microsoft&ModelOrVersion=52A-00004&Type=Hardware&tempOsid=Windows+RT+8.1) does work with Windows RT 8.1. I will update when/if I get one to confirm.

**Update**

I picked up the controller and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does but have to be the Xbox 360/windows controller. There is a red-boxed Xbox 360 styled windows controller that works perfect.